# If mouse movement detected, show cursor in a dialog window C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, cursor, detect, mousemove

The program written in C++ MFC has a Dialog Window which plays a full screen video and the cursor is hidden.

1. I want to display the cursor when there is movement in mouse
   (video is playing in background)
2. Cursor disappears when the mouse is inactive for 3 seconds (Video
   still playing)

Example:It is just like any video player in fullscreen mode, where the controls are hidden if mouse is inactive and mouse movement gets the controls back.

I have tried

```
if(WM_MOUSEMOVE)
{ShowCursor(TRUE)}
```

in the `BOOL CDialog1::OnInitDialog()`

But it shows (TRUE) even if there is no mouse movement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
I have tried if(WM_MOUSEMOVE) {ShowCursor(TRUE)

} in the BOOL CDialog1::OnInitDialog()
```

looks like if it was a pseudo code, `if(WM_MOUSEMOVE)` is equivalent to `if(true)`.

What you should do is to catch `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message and then show your cursor, still inside this message handler set a timer with time for example 3 seconds, in timer handler hide your cursor. Remember to recreate your timer each time `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is received so it will reset it to start counting again from begining.

I am not getting into details, as this question is not on how to receive messages with MFC, right? You dont catch messages inside `OnInitDialog`.

---

```
BOOL CDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  if (pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
  {}
  return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I may not have mentioned this in the Question,  Where do i catch the MouseMove message? define a HRESULT or HCURSOR function?

Comment: @mrudulaw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474863/how-to-capture-mousemove-event-in-a-mfc-dialog-based-application-for-a-checkbox

Comment: BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFlickyFull, CDialogEx)
 ON_WM_PAINT() 
 ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
 ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
void CFlickyFull::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
 // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
 ShowCursor(TRUE);
 
}

If I move the mouse,it should enter the function (MouseMove)? That's not happening when i execute it.

Comment: @mrudulaw I suppose some child controls is eating this message, you might try catching it inside PreTranslateMessage, see my answer for example.

Comment: Ok, now it catches, but it does it after the video is played and stopped. I have written the video play code inside OnPaint().

Comment: @mrudulaw maybe you are blocking OnPaint? This would prevent pretranslatemessage from receiving messages. If that is true then you sholuld follow some video play tutorial, ie.: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/516017/Howplustoplusdiaplayplustheplusvideopluswithinplus, or maybe use DirectShow.